# Use of the `private` (and `define/private`) form in a Racket class

Tags: class, oop, object, racket, scoping

Racket's [`class`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mzlib_class.html?q=class#%28tech._clas%29)s have a `private` form that can be used to hide methods. This seems to mimic use of private in other languages like Java or C#. [The docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createclass.html?q=private#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._private%29%29) show an example of using private to hide a method:

```
(define light%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (define on? #t)
    (define (toggle) (set! on? (not on?)))
    (private toggle)
    (define (flick) (toggle))
    (public flick)))

> (send (new light%) toggle)
send: no such method
  method name: toggle
  class name: light%
> (send (new light%) flick)
```

However, by default methods seem to be private, whether or not there actually is a `private` keyword used. For example, modifying the example from the docs yields the same results:

```
(define light%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (define on? #t)
    (define (toggle) (set! on? (not on?)))
    (define (flick) (toggle))
    (public flick)))

> (send (new light%) toggle)
send: no such method
  method name: toggle
  class name: light%
> (send (new light%) flick)
```

In both cases, scopes outside of the class don't have access to `toggle`, but they do for `flick`, because its marked as `public`.

So then, what is `private` used for, and why is it still in the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, `toggle` is not a method; it is a private field whose value is a closure. In particular, a new `toggle` closure is allocated for every `light%` object.

With `(private toggle)`, the `toggle` method definition is transformed to take an extra argument for `this`, and field references are resolved through that argument.  Something like this:

```
(define (toggle-impl this-obj)
  (set-light%-on?! this-obj (not (light%-on? this-obj))))
```

Since it no longer closes over `this`, the procedure can be allocated once, at the same time as the class. The `class` macro binds `toggle` to a macro that rewrites all calls to `toggle` to pass the implicit `this` argument. (This is why method names are not values; if you want to `map` a method over a list, you must eta-expand so the method name is in operator position.)

Comment: Okay. So it seems like this means that one method is allocated rather than one per each object instance. That makes sense. Can you show me an example where the end result would be different?

Comment: I say that because even 'this', seems to be bound in the private method: (define light%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (field [on? #t])
    (define/private (toggle)
      (set! on? (not on?))
      (displayln (get-field on? this)))
    (define (toggle2)
      (set! on? (not on?))
      (displayln (get-field on? this)))
    (define/public (flick)
      (toggle2)
      (toggle))))

Comment: AH, okay, I think I got it. This only shows up when you don't eta-expand functions. I see, thank you.